# How to create directive in feature model and use in app component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created feature module Add one directive called HighlightDirective to FeatureModule. Use the directive of the FeatureModule in AppModule. If you use this directive for a para, background color of the para should become blue when mouseenter event occurs on the para element and no background color when mouseleave event occurs. If i use HighlightDirective to FeatureModule it's not working. But it is working if i use HighlightDirective to appModule.

My code like below.

feature.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HighlightDirective } from '../highlight.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HighlightDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

highlight.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit, HostListener, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

   constructor(
    private elementRef:ElementRef, 
    private renderer:Renderer2) { }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.color = this.defaultColor;
    }


    @Input() defaultColor;
    @Input() highlight: string= 'lime';

    @HostBinding('style.color') color:string = this.defaultColor;


    @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover(){
      console.log('mouseover');
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');

      this.color=this.highlight;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(){
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'transparent');
      this.color=this.defaultColor;
    }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FeatureModule } from './feature/feature.module';

//import { TestDirective } from './test.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   // TestDirective,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FeatureModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

appcomponent.html

```
<p appHighlight defaultColor="gray">Start editing to see some magic happen</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: It would be better to use a shared module with the directive if you are planning to use that in both the app and feature module.

Comment: Please check it my updated my code @the_mishra

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your feature.component.ts

```
**@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule],
    declarations: [FeatureModule],
    exports: [FeatureModule, CommonModule]
    })
    export class FeatureModuleExtended {}**
```

then in app.module.ts -> import -> FeatureModuleExtended

Comment: there is no feature.component.ts @Nitika

Comment: Just add `exports: [HighlightDirective]` to `feature.module` .

Answer (score 0):

1. [*feature.module.ts*] **declare** your directive

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [HighlightDirective],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ]
    })
```

2. [*feature.module.ts*] **exports** directive

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [HighlightDirective],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      exports: [HighlightDirective]
    })
```

3. [*app.module.ts*] **imports** FeatureModule

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        FeatureModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```